# Using xargs with qmHandle to remove bounce messages

Tags: xargs, qmail

I have almost 100,000 spam messages in my bounce folder for qmail.

I've been trying to use this command:

```
find * | xargs -tl `qmHandle -d$1`
```

But with no success.  I've tried multiple variations.  I also don't have parallel on my machine.

I did try:

```
find * | xargs qmHandle -d
```

But it puts a space between the resulting command of:

```
qmHandle -d 133893
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
find * | xargs -tl -I {} qmHandle -d{}
```